# bash shell sys.path.append problem

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am very new to Linux shell. Does anyone know why I am getting the following error?

```
[root@localhost src]# sys.path.append('/usr/local/folder1/');
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'/usr/local/folder1/''
```

Comment: What were you trying to do at the time of the error? It looks like you tried to run python code in bash or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that is not correct bash syntax.  What you should write is:

```
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/folder1
```

Comment: thanks. what's the difference between sys.path.insert and set it by your way?

Comment: @Nissan911 - the most important difference is my suggestion is proper Bash and your suggestion is for something other language.

Comment: ok thanks. i was trying to add python path. instead of luinx system path. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Appending to sys.path

> > > import sys
> > >
> > > sys.path   # displays all the paths included in sys.path
> > >
> > > sys.path.append("/home/rahul/documents")